# PHP ternary always outputs as if conditional is true

Tags: php, html

In the following code...

```
echo "|".$express_ship."|".is_bool($express_ship)."|".(int)$express_ship."|".is_true($express_ship)."|";
echo '<input type="checkbox" id="express_ship" name="express_ship"'.($express_ship ? ' checked' : '').'/>';
```

... the input box is always checked, even when the echo line before it returns...
|false||0|false|

Any ideas?

It's strange that is_bool($express_ship) returns an empty string. Has anyone encountered this before?

PS: if $express_ship is true, the line before displays as...
|true||0|true|

Addendum: For some reason I thought is_true was a PHP function and I was using this to debug $express_ship. Strangely this never caused an error, even though there is no such function in PHP. (And I have coded no such function of my own.)

Comment: Are you getting any php error?

Comment: Your code works for me when I add before the code `$express_ship = true` or `$express_ship = false`. Where do you declare `$express_ship`? Edit: without declaration box is not checked at all.

Comment: I also tried Pradeep's answer below. Changed the input statement to...
    <input type="checkbox" id="express_ship" name="express_ship"'.(is_true($express_ship) ? ' checked' : '').'/>
Still didn't work.

Comment: @ZZ-bb I echo is_true($express_ship) just before, and it shows false. So $express_ship definitely is false. Perhaps I'll replace the whole thing with an "if" statement to see what happens.

Comment: @AhmedGinani no PHP error.

Comment: @clayRay above code works fine at my end  when `$express_ship = true or $express_ship = false` . check at your end once again.

Comment: Are you sure `$express_ship` is really returning `true` or `false`?

Comment: Could be also some sort of browser compatibility issue. Also try `echo '<input type="checkbox" id="express_ship" name="express_ship"'. (empty($express_ship) ? ' checked' : '') . '/>';` (Anyway, everything works for me with Chrome and Firefox.)

Comment: And please note that my code above and your original code will check the checkbox when ´$express_ship´ is `bool(false)`, `empty/NULL` or `int(0)`.

Comment: @ZZ-bb I have added more information in my answer above. $express_ship is never empty/NULL or int(0). I thought at first it might just be "true" or "false" as a string, but this was not the case, as is_true($express_ship) is returning false and true, depending on the value of $express_ship. It's very strange that is_bool is returning an empty string though.

Comment: try `(isset($express_ship) && $express_ship) ? ' checked' : ''` instead of `($express_ship ? ' checked' : '')`

Comment: thanks @Bhaskar, tried that. Same result. I am at my wits' end.

Comment: I've replaced all the ternary stuff with an "if" statement. Still the same problem. It's as if the Echo statement happens, regardless of the conditional logic around it.

Comment: `is_bool()` returns `true` or `false`. They are rendered in the browser as 1 or '' (empty string) respectively. Btw: what is `is_true()`? There is no such function (out of the box).

Comment: @clayRay Never lose hope. One more try: `$checked =  (isset($express_ship) && $express_ship) ? ' checked' : ''; echo '<input type="checkbox" id="express_ship" name="express_ship"'.$checked.'/>';`

Comment: @Bhaskar thanks for that, it turns out it was a string after all. I was using is_true(), which apparently isn't even a function in PHP but didn't return an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if variable $express_ship is return string like "true" or "false" it will always show your checkbox checked.

you need to update the code like below:

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" id="express_ship" name="express_ship"'.($express_ship == 'true' ? ' checked' : '').'/>';
```

or you need to check by var_dump to find which type of value you get in this variable $express_ship

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please see my modified question.

Comment: Need to check by var_dump and find type of value which is containing by variable $express_ship, according to this you need to apply condition,
if your true and false will return in string instead of boolean, then you should use with ($express_ship == 'true' ? ' checked' : ''), if variable return value in boolean then ($express_ship  ? ' checked' : ''),
Please check type with var_dump($express_ship).

Comment: That's fixed it, thanks! Yes, it turns out in the var_dump that this was a string after all. Apparently there is no is_true function in php. Why that didn't cause an error I don't know.